# ToolStripMenuItem Shortcut Keys, Ctrl-Shift-P vs Ctrl-P

Tags: .net, winforms, keyboard-shortcuts, menuitem

I have shortcut keys set up as follows:

// <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> -> `Print`

```
this.menuCmdPrint.ShortcutKeys = ((System.Windows.Forms.Keys)
    ((System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Control |
      System.Windows.Forms.Keys.P)));
```

// <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> -> `Print Preview`

```
this.menuCmdPrintPreview.ShortcutKeys = ((System.Windows.Forms.Keys)
   (((System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Control |
      System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Shift) |
      System.Windows.Forms.Keys.P)));
```

but the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> combination triggers a `Print`, not a `Preview`.  What am I doing wrong?  If I change it to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>, it properly previews.  I suspect there's some order involved.  When the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> combination is pressed, it somehow checks <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> first, which is satisfied, so it calls the `Print` event handler instead of the `Preview handler`.  Is this a correct assumption?

I tried changing the order of the menu items specified in `MergeIndex`, and also changed the order that the controls were added to the `ToolStripItemCollection`, but no luck.

Comment: Your short cuts look correct.  Sounds like the click event handlers might be mixed up.

Comment: nope, event handlers are correct.  When I change ctrl-shift-P to ctrl-shift-Q, it works properly.

Comment: Hmm, MergeIndex...  You need to document this better.  With the code you posted, I can't reproduce the problem.  If it's not the event handlers, maybe you have code somewhere else looking at key presses?.  Is this an MDI app?  Any other menus in the project that have those short cuts?

Comment: Yes, it is MDI.  No, there are no other menus involved.  I just thought MergeIndex might effect the order of processing.

Comment: The problem could be that when you push Ctr+Shift+P the condition for both shortcuts are met.. maybe you could specify that the shift key should NOT be pressed for the print preview.. (&= ~Keys.Shift)

Comment: I don't think I can do that, at least not in this context.  These shortcut keys were set up through the designer.